# Why don't I need to use borrowed reference in the other function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I was reading a tutorial and with the example of this code It was not mandatory to use the reference in the do_something_else function, but if I created another function I would have to use it. Why isn't it mandatory to use both?

Another thing would be if I added another function then the first two would have to have the reference

```
struct Book {
    title: String
}

fn print_book(book: &Book) {
    println!("Book: {}", book.title);
}

fn do_something_else(book: Book) {
    println!("Again: {}", book.title);
}


fn main() {
    let book = Book {
        title: String::from("The Rust Programming Language")
    };

    print_book(&book);
    do_something_else(book);
}
```

Comment: the use of references in Rust functions is dictated by the ownership model of the language. Whether you pass a value directly or by reference depends on whether you want the function to take ownership of that value or just borrow it temporarily.

Comment: One way to look at it is that if a function takes a reference, then it _borrows_ the value from you. When it has finished using the value, you still have it, so you can do something else with it. Without the reference the function _takes_ the value from you. So even when it has finished using it, you no longer have the value, and therefore you can no longer do anything with it.

Comment: Also, it's not mandatory to use reference in `do_something_else()`, even if you added a third function. You could make `Book` derive `Clone` and pass `book.clone()` to `do_something_else()`. Which option is appropriate depends on what you want to do, and Rust gives you a choice. If in doubt, start out by accepting a reference.

Comment: @Jmb in this case, a "loan" was made to the print_book function, but the other one does not receive this "loan" but still uses this value. What is not clear is that the second function to receive the value does not need to have references and this is not mandatory, but shouldn't it?

Comment: Why would `do_something_else` need to borrow the value since it owns it?

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, each variable has exactly one owner. If you call a function such as `do_something_else`, the function takes ownership of book and book is no longer usable. Because `print_book` only takes a reference, it only borrows the variable without passing ownership.

I would recommend you to read [Chapter 4 of the rust programming language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) or [chapters 15.2 and 15.3 of Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/scope/move.html) in order to get a grasp on how borrowing works, because its an essential concept to the language.

```rust
    struct Book {
        title: String
    }
    
    fn print_book(book: &Book) { //notice that book is of type &Book
        println!("Book: {}", book.title);
        // do_something_else(*book); this would cause an error
        // because book is only borrowed, calling do_something_else
        // would require us to have ownership of book
    }
    
    fn do_something_else(book: Book) { //book is of type Book
        println!("Again: {}", book.title);
    }
    
    
    fn main() {
        let book = Book {
            title: String::from("The Rust Programming Language")
        };
    
        print_book(&book);
        //book is still usable, because print_book only borrowed the variable
        print_book(&book);
        //we can call print_book as often as we like without any errors,
        //because we never pass ownership to print_book
        do_something_else(book);
        //book is no longer usable here because do_something_else has taken ownership of it
        //println("Book {}", book.title);
        // this would not work because book was "consumed" by do_something_else


    }
```